# Neatening up custom event handlers - remove need for 'event' parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building some objects that will trigger custom events, and I'm using jQuery's bind and trigger to manage this for me, like so:

```
function MyObject() {

    var _this = this;

    this.onUpdate = function(fn) {
        $(_this).bind('MyObject.update', fn);
    };

    this.update = function(params) {
        //Do stuff...
        $(_this).trigger('MyObject.update', [updatedID]);
    };

}
```

My problem is when I come to register other callback functions with onUpdate - the functions I pass in need to include the 'event' parameter for trigger to work correctly, like so:

```
function myCallback(event, updatedID) {
    //Do more stuff...
}

var myobject = new MyObject();
myobject.onUpdate(myCallback);
```

Is there a nice way I can wrap the function that I pass in to bind in the onUpdate method, so that myCallback doesn't need the 'event' parameter, as it seems a bit irrelevant for my purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`apply` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply):

```
this.onUpdate = function(fn) {
    $(_this).bind('MyObject.update', function() {
        var params = [].slice.call(arguments, 1); // remove first argument
        fn.apply(this, params);
    });
};
```

---

OT: Instead of adding the functions to each instance, you should extend the functions prototype:

```
MyObject.prototype.onUpdate = function(fn) {...};
MyObject.prototype.update = function(params) {...};
```

This way, all the instances share these functions.

Articles that are worth to be read in this regard:

- [MDN - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)
- [MDN - Details of the object model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model)
- [MDN - Inheritance revisited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited)

Comment: This is spot on thanks very much. I hadn't come across apply before (still getting my feelers out on the javascript side of things). I found this article was quite informative about call and apply for anyone else in the same boat: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx

Comment: Also good point about the use of prototype. It just seemed more natural to me to declare the functions inside the 'class definition' coming from other languages (and in a code cleanliness sense), and I didnt think about the consequences in terms of multiple copies of the function. Does prototype still work from inside by any chance?

Comment: @actionshrimp: What do you mean by *from inside*? Think about the constructor function really as *constructor* and not as "class" definition.

Comment: @actionshrimp: Good :) I added some links about this for further reading. Happy coding!